# Does a batter lose RBI credit for a runner's missed base?"

Tags: baseball, scoring, softball

There is a lot of talk about an appeal play for a missed base with or without runners on base. The problem is no one is talking about the what the batter is credited with. In our case with 2 outs and a runner on first, the batter hits what at first is a triple with the runner scoring. The second baseman calls for an appeal as he feels the runner (not the batter) missed second. The umpire agrees and the runner is ruled out, the run taken away from the offensive team.  The only question is what is the batter credited with?

(If the situation differs between baseball and softball, please include those differences in any answers)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything here where the fact that it's slowpitch softball (rather than MLB baseball) matters.

If I were scoring, I'd credit the batter with a triple.  No run was scored, so there is no RBI to award to the batter, nor a run to award to the runner on first.

There are some situations where the actions of the preceding runner affect the ruling of hit for the batter.  They are described in 9.06(b).  But these situations are only where the runner is put out at third or home, suggesting that they ran into an out.  This specific situation does not apply.

The commentary then says:

> The official scorer shall not, however, with the exception of the
>   above, determine the value of base-hits by the number of bases
>   advanced by a preceding runner. A batter may deserve a two-base hit
>   even though a preceding runner advances one or no bases; a batter may
>   deserve only a one-base hit even though he reaches second base and a
>   preceding runner advances two bases.

Examples then follow that do not involve a runner missing a base.  But by this criteria, I see no reason not to credit the triple.

I went through the [NSA Slow Pitch Softball Rulebook](https://www.playnsa.com/uploads/2018%20NSA%20Slow%20Pitch%20Rulebook.pdf), and it doesn't appear to have a section on scorekeeping.  In the absence of that, I'd follow the MLB scoring.